# Mongoose conditional find

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a store and some products can be unpublished - when viewed on front they are 404. However I would like to preview them if "preview=1" is given in the url. I am looking for an elegant, one liner way to insert that in my find function:

```
var preview = req.param('preview');
Product.findOne({ _id: req.params.id, publish: TRUE_OR_ANY_IF_PREVIEW_SET)}).populate('categories').exec(function(err, product) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite a one-liner, but here's the typical way to do it:

```
var query = {_id: req.params.id};
if (!preview) {
    query.publish: true
}
Product.findOne(query).populate('categories').exec(function(err, product) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.findOne({
  _id: req.param('id')
  publish: req.param('preview') ? true: false
}).populate('categories').exec(function(err, product) { });
```

Comment: That would not work - the issue is that if preview is set then it must allow both true or false so...    req.param('preview') ? true: true AND false